# Working with dates and times with Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, date, time-series

I have a series of values and the date and time they were recorded:

```
   Date    | Time  | Value
--------------------------
    ...    |  ...  | ...
27/10/2021 | 11:42 |  18
27/10/2021 | 21:08 |  24
28/10/2021 | 16:31 |  20
29/10/2021 | 00:19 |  19
    ...    |  ...  |  ...
```

I would like to plot it as a time series, but I can't find good ways to handle the datetimes.

I believe I need to combine dates and times into a single cell. But how do I do that? I could find the functions `DATE`, `DATEVALUE`, `TIME` and `TIMEVALUE` to handle dates and times independently, but nothing to handle them together.
The support for datetimes must be there though, because the function `NOW` returns a datetime, because some charts imply they support "date and time" and because some functions are able to work with datetimes.

I tried to concatenate a date and time together them as strings with the formula:

```
CONCATENATE( TEXT(A2, "dd/mm/yyyy"), " ", TEXT(B2, "hh:mm:ss") )
```

This spits out a string in the same format of `NOW()`, but these strings aren't fully treated as datetimes: I'm unable to change their format and the "Timeline chart" refuses to handle them: it says "First column must contain date, or date and time.".
...Yet some functions can work with these strings as if they were valid datetimes: I can subtract them and obtain the correct time difference, or use functions such as `HOUR` or `MONTH` to extract the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple:

```
=A2 + B2
```

retrives in column C the timestamp
that is recognized by your "Timeline chart"

[image]

Comment: I can't believe how simple this was. It works perfectly. Thank you!